# Highlighting a custom UITableViewCell when overriding drawRect

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So far, to give the illusion of highlighting my cell when taping it, it just implemented `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` like this:

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
}
```

Now I customize the rendering of my cell's contentView (contentView's subview actually) by overriding `drawRect`. The problem is my trick doesn't "do the trick" anymore.

So I thought about implementing `tableView:didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:` like this:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let colors: [CGColor]!
    if isHighlighted {
        colors = [UIColor.blackColor().CGColor, UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 230/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1).CGColor]
    } else {
        colors = [UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor, UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 230/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1).CGColor]
    }

    let rect = self.bounds

    GraphicHelper.drawLinearGradient(context, rect: rect, colors: colors)

    let strokeRect = CGRectInset(rect, 1, 1)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1)
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, strokeRect)

    let separatorColor = UIColor(red: 208/255, green: 208/255, blue: 208/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
    let startPoint = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - 1)
    let endPoint = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width - 1, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - 1)
    GraphicHelper.drawStroke(context, startPoint: startPoint, endPoint: endPoint, color: separatorColor, width: 1)
}
```

It does the trick but only on "long" tap which is completely useless as it doesn't work or brief taps.

Any suggestions on how I could make it happens?

Answer (score 0):

My stupid idea

1. Put `UIImageView` in Custom cells contentview for background purpose. (Set White or transparent image)
2. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` change the image of `UIImageView` and reset last selected cells image.

you also can change background color.